# Debugging with Java/Spring's @Autowired on Eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, dependency-injection, autowired, spring-tool-suite

I have picked up a project that uses @Autowired and dependency injection a lot. People have been saying all the nice things about them. It seems kind of like a magic.

I am new to Spring injection and @Autowired. My first glance of @Autowired is good, but when I work with them on Eclipse, I have difficulties tracing them around when debugging.

For example, is there an easy way in Eclipse that I can see where and how an @Autowired bean is initiated? How do I know if it is initiated correctly the way I want? Is there a way to trace the sequence of it being called/accessed?

Anybody has any tips or comments that may help me to debug @Autowired bean easier on Eclipse?

Comment: Do you have [_Spring Tools_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4) installed in your Eclipse?

Comment: In case you use Spring Tools 4, this might be useful here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Live-Application-Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Spring application starts, it first creates instances of beans, either by scanning for annotations, or processing the XML Spring context definition.  Some of those beans have to be created in a specific order, like if they use constructor injection.  Once beans are created, wiring those beans together can happen.

If you want to see what happens when a bean is constructed, set a breakpoint in the constructors of the class.  Look down the stacktrace to see what caused it to be constructed.

Comment: If a bean is initiated with XML, can I still breakpoint it?

Comment: Of course. This is still just a Java application. The Spring Context, whether defined with annotations, XML, or a combination, just describes the classes and bean names to instantiate.